# Generic interface doesnt return correct type

Tags: java, generics, firebase

I'm wondering why my interface method returns an object type instead of the firebase type I've declared: Code below

```
Public Interface IDatabase<T> {
public T getDatabaseRef(String reference)



public Database implements IDatabase<Firebase>{
public Firebase getDatabaseRef(String reference){
.....
return databaseRef;
```

How I initialize the databse

```
IDatabase database = new Database(..)
```

When I call the method

```
Firebase reference = database.getDatabaseRef();
```

I get incompatible types: Required: Firebase, Found:java.lang.object

I declared firebase as the generic value in the implementation of IDatabase.
Shouldn't it return a firebase value?

Comment: Are you sure you are calling the correct method? `T getDatabaseRef(String reference)` and `Firebase getDatabaseRef(String reference)` are set to `private` and expect an argument of type `String`. You call `database.getDatabaseRef();`, which is a different method.

Comment: Post valid Java code. That's not valid Java code, at all.

Comment: You should have a rawtypes warning from the compiler - this is a good lesson in not ignoring compiler warnings.

Answer (score 5):

When you use raw generic types (i.e. without `<SomeType>`), they default to their upper bound. In your case, this is `java.lang.Object`.

This would be correct:

```
IDatabase<Firebase> database = new Database(..);
```